# Javascript snake pattern grid

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I am trying to draw a grid on screen numbered in a snake pattern in Javascript, I have a working grid but it follows the pattern of

```
12345
67890
```

And what I need is

```
12345
09876
```

I have seen this done with modulo and have tried to implement but im having trouble getting the right number sequence.

Here is my function

```
function createGrid(length, height) {
  var ledNum = 0;
  for (var rows = 0; rows < height; rows++) {
    for (var columns = 0; columns < length; columns++) {
      var backwards = ledNum + columns;

      if (rows % 2 == 0 || rows != 0) {
        $("#container").append("<div class='grid' id='" + ledNum + "'>" + //HERE IS MY PROBLEM+"</div>");
        }
        else if (!rows % 2 == 0) {
          $("#container").append("<div class='grid' id='" + ledNum + "'>" + ledNum + "</div>");
        }
        ledNum++;
      };
    };

    $(".grid").width(960 / length);
    $(".grid").height(960 / height);
  };
```

How do I work out the true modulo case to show the numbers correctly in snake pattern?

I am not well versed with 2d arrays but perhaps that might be a better way?

Comment: Your problem is bigger than just where you put the comment. The boolean logic in your `if ...else if` is wrong in both places. The first condition is always true when `rows != 0`, and the second one does not make much sense: the `!` operator has precedence, so your are doing a modulo operation on a boolean value. And given how the first condition is always true except the first time, the second `if` condition will never be true when it is evaluated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way I can think of is to use an object with arrays and exploit its inbuilt functions to ease your job...for example

```
function createGrid(length,height) {
    var lednum = 0;
    var grid = [];
    for (var row = 0; row < height; row++) {
        grid[row] = [];
        for (var col = 0; col < length; col++) {
            if ((row % 2) === 0) {
                grid[row].push(lednum);
            } else {
                grid[row].unshift(lednum);
            }
            lednum++;
        }
    }
    return grid;
}
console.log(createGrid(10, 10))
```

Then you can just print out above grid

**Update :** How to print above data. You could simply use two for loops.

```
var length = 10;
var height = 15;
var brNode = document.createElement('br');

var grid = createGrid(length, height));

for (var row = 0; row < height; row++) {
    var rowPrint = "";
    for (var col = 0; col < length; col++) {
        rowPrint += String(grid[row][col]) + " ";
    }
    var rowNode = document.createTextNode(rowPrint)
    $("#container").appendChild(rowNode);
    $("#container").appendChild(brNode);
}
```

Note that this will create rows of `textNode` broken by `<br/>` tags. if you want it formatted in some other way..well you have the preformatted data..all you need to do is traverse through it and print it how you want.

Comment: I edited above to remove a few syntax errors but generally this output works for what I need. Once I can out put I will report back

Comment: How would I output this like i do in the example I gave?

Comment: @anthonytherockjohnson The above should do it..but if this is for an actual website I would recommend using more advanced tools to render it and not just textNodes. But that's your prerogative

Answer (score 0):

This general idea seems to work...

```
// Input variables
var data = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
var width = 5;

// The actual algorithm.
var rows = Math.ceil(data.length / width);
for (var y = 0; y < rows; y++) {
  var rowText = "";
  for (var x = 0; x < width; x++) {
    // Basically, for every other row (y % 2 == 1),
    // we count backwards within the row, as it were, while still
    // outputting forward.
    var offset = y * width + (y % 2 == 1 ? width - 1 - x : x);
    rowText += data[offset] || " ";
  }
  console.log(rowText);
}
```

---

```
$ node so51356871.js
abcde
jihgf
klmno
tsrqp
uvwxy
    z
```

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in comments, there is a lot wrong with the boolean logic in your code:

- The first `if` condition always evaluates to true, except in the first iteration
- The second `if` condition is therefor only evaluated once, and it will be false.

I would split the functionality in two parts:

1. Create a 2D array with the numbers in "snake" sequence
2. Create the DOM elements from such a matrix, using some CSS to control the line breaks

```js
function createSnake(width, height) {
    const numbers = [...Array(width*height).keys()];
    return Array.from({length:height}, (_, row) => 
        numbers.splice(0, width)[row % 2 ? "reverse" : "slice"]()); // 2D array
}

function createGrid(matrix) {
    $("#grid").empty().append(
        [].concat(...matrix.map(row => row.map((val,i) => 
            $("<div>").addClass("grid").toggleClass("newline", !i).text(val))))
    );
}

// Demo generating a 3 x 3 grid
createGrid(createSnake(3,3));
```

```css
.grid {
    float: left;
    padding: 3px;
}
.newline {
    clear:left
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="grid"></div>
```